# Open neighborhoods in the set of $K=\prod_1^{\infty}\{0,1\}$

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, hilbert-spaces, cantor-set

The problem given to me goes as follows:

Define $K=\prod_1^{\infty}\{0,1\}$, in the product topology. Let $S=s_n$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers such that $\sum_1^{\infty}s_i=1$. Define a map such that $f_s:K\rightarrow[0,1]$ by $k\mapsto \sum_1^{\infty}s_ik_i$. Show that $f_S$ is continuous.

I was thinking that the easiest way to show this would be to take an open neighborhood $V$ in $[0,1]$ (so it is of the form $(a,b)$) and show that $f_S^{-1}(V)$ is open.

But I am having troubles understanding what open sets in $K$ look like, can someone give me an example?

In addition if you think there is an easier way to show this, I would be welcome to suggestions.

Comment: What are the open sets for your topology on $\{0,1\}$?  $\tau = \{ \varnothing, \{0,1\}, \{0\}, \{1\} \}$, or $\tau = \{ \varnothing, \{0,1\} \}$?  Then you can work out what the open cylinders in the product topology are.

Comment: The question says that $K$ is the set of all sequences of zeros and ones given the product topology, and I think that is what is tripping me up. I think the product of open neighborhoods is the open neighborhood in the product topology, but I guess I am not sure

Comment: So $K = \prod_{i=1}^\infty S_i$ where each $S_i$ is its own topological space, and the product topology on $K$ is constructed in a particular way from the topologies on each of the $S_i$.  Each of your $S_i$ looks to me like a discrete space, $\{0,1\}$.  So you have to put a topology on each of those spaces to decide what the product topology on $K$ is, to answer a question like, "what is an open set in $K$".  But that's just how I would approach the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x=\langle x_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in K$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$B_n(x)=\{\langle y_i:i\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in K:y_i=x_i\text{ for }i=1,\ldots,n\}\;;$$

$B_n(x)$ is a basic open set in the product topology, and it’s not hard to check that $\{B_n(x):n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is a nbhd base at $x$ in $K$. You can use this to show that if a sequence in $K$ converges to $x$, its image under $f$ converges to $f(x)$ and hence that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by nbhd base at $x$ in $K$.

Comment: @NewbieMather: A neighborhood base at the point $x$: a family $\mathscr{B}$ of open sets containing $x$ with the property that every open set containing $x$ contains some member of $\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you

Comment: Does this also refer to the pre-image of open is open definition of continuity??

Comment: @NewbieMather: You can use it that way, yes. Show that if $f(x)=a$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $f(y)\in(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ for each $y\in B_n(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find this easier to visualize by using the neighbourhood version of continuity.

Fix $x\in K$ and $\varepsilon>0$. By convergence, there is some $n$ such that $\sum_{i>n} s_i <\varepsilon$. Let $U=\bigcap_{i\le n}\{ y\in K: y_i=x_i\}$. This set is open in the product topology and, given any $y\in U$,
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|= \sum_{i>n} s_i <\varepsilon
$$

Comment: Where $\epsilon$ is the neighborhood in $[0,1]$ right?

Comment: Yes, I'm playing a bit fast and loose there. If you want to be more succinct, the natural extension $f:K\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous (the proof I just gave works), and thus so is $f:K\to [0,1]$ with the subspace (i.e. usual) topology in the codomain.

Comment: I'll also add the following, important fact: when taking products of discrete spaces, two sequences are close to each other iff they agree on an initial segment. The longer the segment they agree on, the closer they are. This is what makes the proof work.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Thank you!