# Show that $f_S$ is surjective/injective

Tags: general-topology, functions

[Open neighborhoods in the set of $K=\prod_1^{\infty}\{0,1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626955/open-neighborhoods-in-the-set-of-k-prod-1-infty-0-1?noredirect=1#comment7454557_3626955)

Using the same mapping given in the question linked above, I need to show that if $s_k\leq\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty}s_i$ then $f_S$ is surjective, and $s_k>\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty}s_i$ then $f_S$ is injective.

I know that with surjectivity, you take $y\in[0,1]$ and show that there is some $k\in K$ such that $f(k)=y$, and that with injectivity, you take $y_1,y_2\in[0,1]$ and show that $y_1=y_2$ implies $k_1=k_2$.

My problem is understanding how the given hypothesis' works inside this.

What I have tried to do goes as follows.

\begin{align*}
y &=0.a_1a_2a_3...\\
&=\sum_1^{\infty}s_ik_i\\
&\geq\sum_{k+1}^{\infty}s_ik_i+s_kk_k\\
&=f((k_1,k_2,...,k_{k-1},0,...)+(0,...,k_k,0...))
\end{align*}
Thus there exists a $k\in K$ that maps to $y$ and our function is surjective. I am aware it is wrong, but I am not sure how to fix it.

For injectivity I have:
Let $y_1,y_2\in[0,1]$ such that $y_1=y_2$. Then
\begin{align*}
y_1&=y_2\\
\sum_1^{\infty}s_ik_i&=\sum_1^{\infty}s_jk_j\\
\sum_{k+1}^{\infty}s_ik_i+s_kk_k&=\sum_{k+1}^{\infty}s_jk_j+s_kk_k\\
f(k_1,k_2,...,k_i,0...)&=f(k_1,k_2,...,k_j,0...)\\
\implies k_m&=k_n \hspace{10mm}\text{for every }m,n
\end{align*}
Thus $k_1=k_2$, and the function is injective. Again I am pretty sure that this is wrong, but I am not sure what I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really two problems; let’s stick with just one of them for now. I’ll sketch an argument for the first part; see if you can complete it.

As you say, to show that $f$ is surjective, you must show that if $y\in[0,1]$, there is some $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in K$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z^+}s_kx_k=y$. There is one pretty straightforward way to try to find such an $x$. If $s_1\le y$, let $x_1=1$, and otherwise let $x_1=0$; this ensures that $s_1\le f(x)\le y$. In general, if you’ve defined $x_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,\ell$, let $x_{\ell+1}=1$ if $\sum_{k=1}^{\ell+1}s_kx_k\le y$, and otherwise let $x_{\ell+1}=0$. In this way you recursively construct $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in K$ in such a way that $\sum_{k=1}^\ell s_kx_k\le y$ for each $\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$. Note that the sequence

$$\left\langle\sum_{k=1}^\ell s_kx_k:\ell\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$$

of partial sums is non-decreasing and bounded above by $y$, so does converge; its limit is by definition $f(x)$, and it’s clear that $f(x)\le y$. Now assume that $s_k\le\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty s_i$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ and try to show that in this case $f(x)=y$, i.e., that $f(x)$ cannot be strictly less than $y$.

The most natural approach is to assume that $f(x)<y$ and try to get a contradiction. Suppose that infinitely many of the $x_k$ are $0$. Show that there must be a $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x_k=0$ **and** $s_k<y-f(x)$. This is impossible, because in that case we would have set $x_k=1$, since $\sum_{i=1}^ks_ix_i<y$. Thus, $\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:x_k=0\}$ must be finite. (It must also be non-empty; why?)

Now let $\ell=\max\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:x_k=0\}$, and get a contradiction by showing that we would in fact have set $x_\ell=1$ at that stage of the construction of $x$.

Comment: So essentially you are using the greedy algorithm to show that f(x)=y?

Comment: @NewbieMather: I’m using a greedy algorithm to construct a good candidate for an $x\in K$ such that $f(x)=y$, yes. That seems to me the most natural way to proceed, and the real work then is in showing that this candidate really does work.

Comment: And the reason that it comes to the contradiction is because if we have something that ends in 0's, we could have used a greedy algorithm to pick 1 instead?

Comment: @NewbieMather: No, there are only finitely many zeroes, so it ends in ones. What you have to do is use the condition that $s_k\le\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty s_i$ for each $k$ to show that the very last $0$ that we chose should have been a $1$.

Comment: Oh! Got it. Thank you so much for explaining it to me

Comment: @NewbieMather: You’re welcome.